# I'm trying to raise numbers to their consecutive powers and my code isn't working

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/aholston/pen/ZJbrjd

The codepen link has commented code as well as actual instructions in HTML

Otherwise.... what I ultimately have to do is write a function that takes two params(a and b) and takes all the numbers between those two params (a-b) and put every number that can be added to the consecutive fowers and be equal to that number into a new array. Ex: 89 = 8^1 + 9^2 = 89 or 135 = 1^1 + 3^2 + 5^3 = 135

```
function sumDigPow(a, b) {
    // Your code here
    var numbers = [];
    var checkNum = [];
    var finalNum = [];
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
        if (i >= a && i <= b) {
            numbers.push(i);
        }
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
        var checkNum = numbers[x].toString().split('');
        if (checkNum.length == 1) {
            var together = parseInt(checkNum);
            finalNum.push(together);
        } else if (checkNum.length > 1) {
            var together = checkNum.join('');
            var togNumber = parseInt(together);

            for (var y = checkNum.length; y > 0; y--) {
                total += Math.pow(checkNum[y - 1], y);
            }
            if (total == togNumber) {
                finalNum.push(togNumber);
            }

        }
    }
    return finalNum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Will, I am currently learning how to debug now. I'm pretty much brand new at this so bare with me!! lol

Comment: Okay Will, I debugged it and figured it out. I'm going to post an answer. Again, thanks a bunch for introducing me to debugging.

Comment: Aaaah! Success!

Comment: @Will until I clicked the link, I read that as "node-bugging", I was like "what...?"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function listnum(a, b) {
  var finalNum = [];
  for (var i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    var x = i;
    var y = i;
    var tot = 0;
    j = i.toString().length;
    while (y) {
      tot += Math.pow((y%10), j--);
      y = Math.floor(y/10);
    }
    if (tot == x)
    finalNum.push(i);
  }
  return finalNum;
}
console.log(listnum(1, 200));
```

Comment: Bibek Shah, your solution definitely works but why in the world does mine not? lol

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after debugging this is what I learned.

```
          for (var y = checkNum.length; y > 0; y--) {
            total += Math.pow(checkNum[y - 1], y);
        }
        if (total == togNumber) {
            finalNum.push(togNumber);
        }

    }
}
return finalNum;
```

}

Everytime this loop happened, I neglected to reset the 'total' variable back to 0. So I was never getting the right answer for my Math.pow() because my answer was always adding to the previous value of total. In order to fix this, I added var total = 0; after i decided whether or not to push 'togNumber' into 'finalNum.' So my code looks like this..

```
for (var y = checkNum.length; y > 0; y--) {
total += Math.pow(checkNum[y - 1], y);


}
if (total == togNumber) { 


finalNum.push(togNumber);}

}
  var total = 0;
}
return finalNum;

 }
```